# Break loop if true - evaluate list for value, and if the value is found, break the loop, else, search for the next value

Tags: foreach, velocity, break

I am trying to evaluate a list of items in Project.SecurityDataTypes and see which is the highest value.
I want it to evaluate all items in the list to see if one is any have InfoTypeAvailability set to "High", and if any one has a value of "High", break out of the loop and set $HWAvail = "High".
If none have a value of "high", evaluate all to see if any have a value of "Moderate", and if so, set $HWAvail to "Moderate" and break out of the loop.
Else, if none have a value of "high" or "moderate", see if any have a value of "low" and set $HWAvail to "low".

I'm pretty new to this. This is the code I have. Unfortunately, it just evaluates the first item in the list, and returns it's value. How can I make it evaluate the whole list and find the highest value (high water mark)?

```
#set($HWAvail = "")
    
#foreach ($InformationType in $Project.SecurityDataTypes)
    #if($InfoTypeAvailability == "High")
        #set($HWAvail = "High")
        #break
    #elseif($InfoTypeAvailability == "Moderate")
        #set($HWAvail = "Moderate")
        #break
    #elseif($InfoTypeAvailability == "Low")
        #set($HWAvail = "Low")
#end
#end
#set ($rec = { 'HWAvail' : $HWAvail })
#set ($n = $MyInfoTypes.add($rec))
#end
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Sara Please tell us what happens when you run this code.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the variable `$InfoTypeAvailability` in your `foreach` clause, this may be a typo and you actually want to use `$InformationType`:

```
#foreach ($InformationType in $Project.SecurityDataTypes)
    #if($InformationType.equals("High"))
        #set($HWAvail = "High")
    #elseif($InformationType.equals("Moderate"))
        #set($HWAvail = "Moderate")
    #elseif($InformationType.equals("Low"))
        #set($HWAvail = "Low")
    #end
#end
```

I'm not sure if `#break` is valid in velocity so I've removed it in case it is. Also assuming `$InformationType` is a `String` I've used the `equals` method rather than use `==`. (Though that may work too).